# How to create a regular expression to search for a substring with numbers?

Tags: python, regex

There are lines with a title element and a value element, with a symbol `-->` is indicated what values I need to get:

```
BATE Borisov
BATE Borisov -0.5, -1.0 --> -0.5, -1.0
Under 2.5 --> 2.5
BATE Borisov
BATE Borisov 0.0, -0.5 --> 0.0, -0.5
Over 1.0 --> 1.0
BATE Borisov -2.5 --> -2.5
Over 1.5 --> 1.5
Over 2.0, 2.5 --> 2.0, 2.5
Over 2.5 --> 2.5
Over 3.5 --> 3.5
Under 2.5 & yes
```

I wrote the following expression:

```regex
((\s|\W)\d+?.+?)(^\..|$)
```

In most cases, it works, except for the last line `Under 2.5 & Yes`, here it finds `2.5 & Yes`, although this is also part of the header. 
Can I somehow indicate in the regular expression that all characters in it should be only numbers or not letters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get all the digits till you reach the end of the string  `$` which will prevent matching the line ending with  `& yes`

```
-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:, -?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)*$
```

*Explanation*

- `-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?` Match 1+ digits with an optional decimal value
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `, -?\d+(?:\.\d+)?` Match a comma, space and a digit with an optional decimal value
- `)*` Close group and repeat 0+ times
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7OHUqq/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/7lpJkt)

*Example code*

```
import re

strings = [
    "BATE Borisov",
    "BATE Borisov -0.5, -1.0",
    "Under 2.5",
    "BATE Borisov",
    "BATE Borisov 0.0, -0.5",
    "Over 1.0",
    "BATE Borisov -2.5",
    "Over 1.5",
    "Over 2.0, 2.5",
    "Over 2.5",
    "Over 3.5",
    "Under 2.5 & yes"
]

regex = r"-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:, -?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)*$"
for s in strings:
    matches = re.search(regex, s)
    if matches:
        print(matches.group())
```

*Output*

```
-0.5, -1.0
2.5
0.0, -0.5
1.0
-2.5
1.5
2.0, 2.5
2.5
3.5
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use the following regex to match a CSV list of positive/negative floats:

```
\b-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:, -?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)*
```

Sample scripts:

```
inp = "BATE Borisov -0.5, -1.0"
matches = re.findall(r'\b-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:, -?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)*', inp)
print(matches)
```

This prints:

```
['0.5, -1.0']

inp = "Under 2.5 & yes"
matches = re.findall(r'\b-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:, -?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)*', inp)
print(matches)
```

This prints:

```
['2.5']
```